# How to custom render autocomplete as a option group?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I trying to render autocomplete as option group depending on object `type` .But it render only `<div><select>` ! option is not included ! I want to show option group autocomplete ?

#### wanted render style

```
<div class="input-field col s12 ui-menu-divider ui-widget-content">
   <select>
     <optgroup label='project'>
          <option value='1'>One</option>
          <option value='2'>Two</option>
     </optgroup>
     <optgroup label='history'>
          <option value='1'>Pending</option>
          <option value='2'>David</option>
     </optgroup>
     <optgroup label='user'>
          <option value='1'>James</option>
     </optgroup>
   </select>
</div>
```

My current code

```
<input type="text">

<script type="text/javascript">
 var source = [
                {id:1,name:"One",type:"project"},
                {id:2,name:"Two",type:"project"},
                {id:1,name:"Crmotion",type:"history"},
                {id:2,name:"David",type:"history"},
                {id:1,name:"Aung Naing",type:"user"}
            ];


$("input").autocomplete({
                    minLength: 1,
                    source: source,
                    id: 'input_search_autocomplete',
                    max: 10,
                    scroll: true,

                    focus: function (event, ui) {
                        alert("s");
                        $("input").val(ui.item.value);
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        
                    }

                }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                    var option = $("<select>");
                    for(var data in item) {
                        var _option_html = $('<optgroup label="'+item[data].type+"'>");
                        _option_html.append('<option value="'+item[data].id+'">'+item[data].name+'</option>').appendTo(option);
                    }
                    return $('<div class="input-field col s12">')
                            .append(option)
                            .appendTo(ul);
                };
</script>
</body>
```